# Where is the CheckoutController#edit in spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spree

I need to play with `edit` action of the CheckoutController, and I see it in server logs, I see it in [documentation](http://edgeguides.spreecommerce.com/checkout.html) but I can't find it in gem's code.

Where's the magic? Spree version is 1.2.2

Comment: You should state your spree version in the question as the location may change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it inside the `spree_core` gem in

```
spree_core-1.3.0/app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller.rb
```

You might find useful to use tools such as [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) to search files. I found it by running `ack-grep CheckoutController` inside the gems directory.

Note that `ack-grep` is just an alias for `ack` to avoid name collision on ubuntu.

Comment: I'm comfortable with searching through gems, but there's no edit action in the checkout_controller

Comment: I am not familiar with spree's codebase, but technically there doesn't need to be any edit action as long as there's its template (checkout/edit.html.*). Might that be the case?

Comment: Jiri is probably correct.  If there's no method defined, and there doesn't seem to be one here, the view of the same name is rendered by default.