# spree custom error: how to trigger error in related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

in spree i've added an uniqueness constraint for the :sku attribute

```
#In spree/models/variant_decorator.rb

Spree::Variant.class_eval do
    validate :sku, :uniqueness => true
 end

Spree::Admin::ProductsController.class_eval do

 # controllers/spree/admin/product_controller_decorator.rb
def update
  if params[:product][:collection_ids].present?
    params[:product][:collection_ids] = params[:product][:collection_ids].split(',')
  end
  if params[:product][:taxon_ids].present?
    params[:product][:taxon_ids] = params[:product][:taxon_ids].split(',')
  end
  @product.errors[:name] = "Trying to trigger an error"
  @product.errors[:base] = "Trying to trigger an error"
  flash[:warning] << "Custom Error"     
  super
  end
end
```

On the /products/:product_id/edit/, even though the uniqueness of the sku is being validated, the error is not displayed when validation fails. How do I trigger the validation error to be displayed? I've tried modifying both the controller and the model. Thanks in advance.

I am using Rails 3.2 and running Spree 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that :sku belongs to the master model whereas most of the other params belonged to the products model.
products/:product_id/edit actually only displayed validation information for the products model, so what I had to do was

1. add validation on the associated model variant within the product
2. copy over any errors from variant.errors to product.errors
3. add validation to the variant model (same as before)

Both of these changes were made in app/models/views/product_decorator.rb
To add validation to the related model, I added the following code,

```
#app/models/spree/product_decorator.rb
validates_associated :variants, :variants_including_master, :master #validation just master should work too
```

And to copy errors from master.errors to product.errors I wrote a callback that copies the errors after_validaiton

```
#app/models/spree/product_decorator.rb
after_validation :merge_master_errors
def merge_master_errors
  self.master.errors.each do |attribute, message|
    self.errors.add(attribute, message)
  end
end
```

For 3:

```
#app/models/spree/variant_decorator.rb
validates :sku, :uniqueness => true
```

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/abf38b0fa5a970953c86c73c7f1f2828c43cba3a/core/app/models/spree/product.rb

Notes: Even though the Product controller has no code for the edit action by [default the corresponding #{action}.html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071372/where-is-the-checkoutcontrolleredit-in-spree) is rendered. I was able to find it in `.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3/bundler/gems/spree-<special-hash-or-version>/backend/app/views/spree/admin/products/edit.html.erb` (this was visible in the rails server stdout) and added some "print statements to the html" e.g.

```
<%= debug @product %>
<%= product.errors.to_hash %>
<%= @product.errors.any? %>
```